# Not switching to next activity

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi I am new to android app development project and i have created a login screen that intends to dashboard avtivity. i have made a button in dashboard to intent to another activity but when i click on the button instead of switchid the ac. tivity it crashes and send back to login screen. Any help will be appreciatd.
This is my intent code.

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cv_btn);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "Make your CV easy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent cvintent;
            cvintent= new Intent(Dashboard.this, CV.class);
            startActivity(cvintent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

`xml` file of the button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/cv_btn"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Make Your CV"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    />
```

Comment: Have you registered your `CV` activity in manifest file?

Comment: post your error code

Comment: @suman paste your crash log instead of xml file

Comment: crash log plse?? check your manifest if DashboardActivity is registered

Comment: Thanks for the tips . It seems to be found that i missed call the type. problem solved thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I run those code you posted without any problem and all things worked properly. I think you've got a problem in you CV activity or maybe in your manifest/build configuration.

[image][image]